# Dialogflow Fulfillment: Fixing Chatbot Response

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am creating a chatbot for my final year project. I am using Dialogflow for it. It's going pretty good but, my chatbot doesn't say the conv.ask statements which are in the Fulfillment. It just repeats the same entity that I have used it for. These same statements will display in the Web Demo and Test Console provided on the Dialogflow website, but not on my app.

This is the Fulfillment code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google')

const Minerals_INTENT ='Mineral'
const Minerals_ENTITY ='Minerals'

const app = dialogflow()

app.intent( Minerals_INTENT , (conv) => { 
const mineral_type = conv.parameters[Minerals_ENTITY];
if(mineral_type == "Calcium")
{
     conv.ask("Sources: Green leafy vegetables, legumes, tofu, molasses, 
sardines, okra, perch, trout, Chinese cabbage, rhubarb, sesame seeds")
}
else if(mineral_type == "Phosphorus")
{
    conv.ask("Toxicity: Very rare. May result in soft tissue 
calcification. \n Sources: Legumes, nuts, seeds, whole grains, eggs, 
fish, 
buckwheat, seafood, corn, wild rice")
}
else if(mineral_type == "Potassium")
{
 conv.ask("Sources: Sweet potato, tomato, green leafy vegetables, 
carrots, 
prunes, beans, molasses, squash, fish, bananas, peaches, apricots, melon, 
potatoes, dates, raisins, mushrooms")
}
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

This is my 'Text or SSML Response'

```
$Minerals
```

This is the code on my Android Studio's chatbot page

```
package com.example.ft.aidt;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import ai.api.AIListener;
import ai.api.android.AIConfiguration;
import ai.api.android.AIService;
import ai.api.model.AIError;
import ai.api.model.AIResponse;
import ai.api.model.Result;
import ai.api.ui.AIDialog;

public class ai extends AppCompatActivity implements AIListener {
public static final String TAG = ai.class.getName();
private Button bu,nu;
private TextView resp;
private  AIService aiService;
private TextView a;
private ImageView yu;
private  TextToSpeech joi;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ai);
    yu  =  (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView20);
    int permi = 
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);
     if(permi != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
     {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         MakeRequest();
     }
    final AIConfiguration config = new 
 AIConfiguration("b0369e8530c14cc0990cccab8b9f0289",
            AIConfiguration.SupportedLanguages.English,
            AIConfiguration.RecognitionEngine.System);

     aiService = AIService.getService(this, config);
    aiService.setListener(this);
    bu =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    resp=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        joi = new TextToSpeech(ai.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {

        }
    });
    yu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ai.this,"Here you can talk to AIDT and converse 
 with it. If you fail to get a reply, please check your internet 
 connection.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    bu.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            resp.setText("ERROR");
            return false;
        }
    });
    bu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             aiService.startListening();
         }
     });
}
protected void MakeRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] 
{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},007);

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] 
grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 007: {

            if (grantResults.length == 0
                    || grantResults[0] !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            } else {
            }
            return;
        }}}

@Override
public void onResult( final  AIResponse response) {


        Log.i("", response.toString());
        ArrayList<String> ap = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> apk = new ArrayList<>();
        final Result result1 = response.getResult();
        String parameterString = "";
        if (result1.getParameters() != null && 
!result1.getParameters().isEmpty()) {
            for (final Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : 
result1.getParameters().entrySet()) {
                parameterString += "(" + entry.getKey() + ", " + 
entry.getValue() + ") ";
            }
        }
        final String sppech = result1.getFulfillment().getSpeech();
        String ae = result1.getResolvedQuery().toString();

        a.setText("\n Baymax: " + result1.getFulfillment().getSpeech());
        resp.setText("\n You: " + result1.getResolvedQuery());
        // Show results in TextView.


        joi.speak(result1.getFulfillment().getSpeech(), 
TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
    }


@Override
public void onError(AIError error)
{
 resp.setText(error.toString());
}

@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}

@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {


}

@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {

}

@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {

}
}
```

[App Screenshot][1]

[Intent, Entity & Test Console Screenshot][1]

```
[1]: https://imgur.com/a/Qs0CWhK "App Screenshot"
[2]: https://imgur.com/a/v3dz2tI "Intent, Entity & Test Console Screenshot"
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the "Mineral" Intent? To make sure I understand, exactly what do you get back when you try this in the Dialogflow simulator and in your Android app? Have you tried it in the Action simulator?

Comment: @Prisoner I have added the screenshots from my mobile app, as well as my Dialogflow for your reference. I would really love some help from you. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you set both screenshots to the same page. Not sure I get what the Intent, Entities, and Console look like.

Comment: I am really sorry. My head's been a mess lately because of this. I have hopefully given you the right content this time. @Prisoner Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using the actions-on-google library to send information back, but your Android App is not an Action. So it is reading the standard Dialogflow fields from a response, rather than looking in the "google" payload section.

In general, if you're planning to develop for platforms other than the Assistant, you should be using the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library, rather than actions-on-google, since it lets you specify custom payloads for your platform.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. But could you please help me figure it out, is there any way I can get in touch with you? I am having troubles with node.js, can we integrate it with Android Studio, where we designed our app?

Comment: Although contact information is in my profile, I do charge for private consultations. I'm willing to help publicly as long as the results remain public, thus helping everyone. You can certainly run the fulfillment on any server that is capable of handling a webhook. I don't know if Android Studio specifically supports managing server code, but I don't see why it wouldn't.